# Извлечь несколько значений из Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть коллекция, в которой каждому элементe соответствует 4 значения(один из них, это имя, которое отображается свойством DisplayMember в комбобоксе и которая является содержимым комбобокса). Остальные 3 нужно извлечь и поместить в функцию. Если было бы нужно извлечь одно значение, то подошло бы свойство ValueMember и затем, с помощью SelectedValue присвоить его переменной, которая попадет в функцию. Есть ли аналог для нескольких значений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, у тебя коллекция, в которой каждому элементу соответсвует 4 свойства, 2 ты биндишь, а остальные хочешь дополнительно получить?

В таком случае, ты в `SelectedItem` должен находится объект, который можно привести к нужному типу и получить доступ к элементам, которые не отображаются в контроле.

Пример:

```
var selVal = (Product) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Расширенный пример:

```
namespace TestProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class Product
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Cnt { get; set; }
        }

        List<Product> listProd;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listProd = new List<Product>();
            listProd.Add(new Product() { id = 2, Name = "Прод 2", Cnt = 2 });
            listProd.Add(new Product() { id = 3, Name = "Прод 3", Cnt = 4 });
            comboBox1.DataSource = listProd;
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selVal = (Product) comboBox1.SelectedItem;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: привет. у меня коллекция выглядит так - List<Product> list = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product("Name", 505, 7, 1.5)
            }; Имя идет в отображения, а 3 значения хочу извлечь в функцию.

Comment: По идее ты можешь привести SelectedValue к типу Product и обратиться к выбранному продукту и к полям, которых не видно на форме.

Comment: Можно какой-нибудь пример. Не совсем понятно, как привести к Product и обратиться к полям, определенным в коллекции?

Comment: @cruim, добавил.

Comment: странно, студия ошибки не выдает. потом через эту переменную обращаюсь к нужному полю. но в процессе компиляции выскакивает ошибка о невозможности приведения типа int к пользовательскому типу Product.

Comment: @cruim, я расширил пример. В дебаггере я вижу, что при нажатии на кнопку в selVal заносится нужный мне объект.

Comment: моя ошибка, вместо comboBox1.SelectedItem использовал SelectedValue. Еще раз спасибо.